# Start a new Activity from LinearLayout class that implements OnClickListener

Tags: android-intent, start-activity

I want to start a new activity from onClick method inside my LinearLayout class that implements OnClickListener.  Below is the code that I used:

`public class act_signature_capture extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener {`

```
LinearLayout buttonsLayout;
SignatureView signatureView;
private Context context;

public act_signature_capture(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    this.buttonsLayout = this.buttonsLayout();
    this.signatureView = new SignatureView(context);

    // add the buttons and signature views
    this.addView(this.buttonsLayout);
    this.addView(signatureView);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String tag = v.getTag().toString().trim();

    // save the signature
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("save")) {
        this.saveImage(this.signatureView.getSignature());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, act_main.class);
        this.context.startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        this.signatureView.clearSignature();
    }
}
```

I cannot switch to my act_main activity with startActivity. Your help will be greatly appreciated.